# how to set the height of the swf file posted to facebook feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How do I set the height of the swf file posted to facebook feed using the PHP API.

Here is my code. It is working fine but I cant find a parameter to set the height.It height is automatically set to 259px. I tried the extended_height parameter also but no luck. Do I have to use the REST API?

```
$options = array(
        'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
    'name' => 'Test App',
    'caption' => "Created using my test app",
    'picture' => $apppath.'Icon.jpg',
    'source' => $apppath.'main.swf',    
    'description' => "Description field",
    'actions' => array( 'name' => 'Click me', 'link' => 'http://www.google.com' )
    );

$wallPost = $facebook->api('/'.$friendid.'/feed', 'post', $options);
```

Anybody got a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/

it shows how attachments are made. Plus if you want you can even use open graph tags in your page to show the media once your page is shared via FB